# expect(klass).to receive(:new) syntax

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've expected the following to work

```
expect(UserUpdateService).to receive(:new)
```

but it's throws an expection

```
undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007faa044d42d8>
```

The 'old' syntax, however, works:

```
UserUpdateService.should_receive(:new)
```

Any idea why the first/new syntax throws an exception?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: ahm, why not? I though that the should syntax is deprecated.

Comment: Why yes? Is there a piece of code in rspec documentation that says you can do this?

Comment: http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/ documents the new syntax. should_receive is the old way, expect().to receive the new one. I thought that's also valid for classes, didn't see a reason why this should not be the case.

Comment: It should work, indeed. What is your version of rspec? Should >= 2.14.

Comment: Also, the blog post says you have to enable new syntax in your spec_helper.rb

Comment: Alright, that worked! I was stuck on rspec 2.13.x. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example passes with rspec 2.14.1

```
specify do
  expect(UserUpdateService).to receive(:new)
  UserUpdateService.new
end
```

Comment: true, my problem was that I was still running rspec 2.13.x where the expect/receive syntax is already working for objects, as it seems